# How do I get the Data out of this XML in TSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, xml-parsing

In a sql query i run these commands and i keep getting NUll no matter what i try.

```
DECLARE @x AS XML

SET @x = ' <Data> <Preference>Mail</Preference>   <Comment>Changed Contact Communication Preference due to customer unsubscribed</Comment>  </Data> '


SELECT @x.value('(//Data/@Preference)[0]','varchar(20)') AS Preference
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath instead:

```
SELECT @x.value('(//Data/Preference)[1]','varchar(20)') AS Preference
```

All XPath arrays are **1-based** - not 0-based - therefore your `[0]` won't return anything.

And secondly, `<Preference>` is an XML element - not an attribute. The `@Preference` you have is trying to select a XML **attribute**